# How to calculate profile completion percentage in TypeOrm, Nest js

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have three tables user, userCareerProfile, userPersonalProfile. userCareerProfile and userPersonalProfile tables is with @OneToOne relationship with user table.

I am trying to calculate the profile completion percentage based on the fields which has data.

**User Entity:**

```
@Entity({ name: 'users' })
export class User extends AbstractEntity {
    @Column({ unique: true })
    email: string;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 50 })
    full_name: string;

    @OneToOne(() => UserPersonalProfile, (details) => details.user)
    personal_details: UserPersonalProfile;

    @OneToOne(() => UserCareerProfile, (career) => career.user)
    career_profile: UserCareerProfile;

}
```

**Personal Profile Entity:**

```
@Entity()
export class UserPersonalProfile extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 20, nullable: true })
    date_of_birth: string;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 200, nullable: true })
    address: string;

    .....

    @OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.personal_details, {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
    user: User;

}
```

**Career Profile Entity:**

```
@Entity()
export class UserCareerProfile extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 100, nullable: true })
    job_role: string;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 100, nullable: true })
    work_location: string;

   .....

    @OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.career_profile, {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
    user: User;

}
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on what do you mean by 'profile completion'? Perhaps provide some sample data in each tables and what expected output you looking for.

Comment: Need more infomation as to how do you calculate `profile completion` from a domain perspective. Is it what fields are filled in `UserCareerProfile` / `UserPersonalProfile` ? Or is it something else entirely ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// count of all fields in object
const fieldCount = Object.keys(yourJSON).length;

// count of filled fields 
const fieldFilledCount = Object.keys(yourJSON.filter(field => field !== null)).length;

// percent of completion
const percent = (fieldFilledCount / fieldCount) * 100;
```